# Resizing image from the center in moviepy

Tags: python, moviepy

So I have an issue with moviepy and applying resize effects.

Creating the image using:

```
img_clip_pos = ("center", "center")

clip = ImageClip(image_path) \
    .set_position(img_clip_pos) \
    .set_duration(req_dur)
```

Then I want it to scale over time, like a zoom effect.

```
clip = clip.fx(vfx.resize, lambda t: 1 + zoom_speed * t)
```

But it's zooming in to the top left corner.
Is there any option to set anchor point of the image? So that I can make it resize from center

Comment: I don't know or use `moviepy` but you probably want to set the *"gravity"* option to *"center"* if you can find it.